# Does AWS EB instance automatically restart when crashed?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, forever

I have a NodeJS instance running with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I would like to know if the instance will automatically restart if nodejs crash the server ?
Do I have to use foreverjs ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

TLDR - Use foreverjs.

So there are two types of restarts. One is where the code throws an exception and stops node. The OS is still running. In this case, from the OS perspective, node decided to exit. None of its business. This is where foreverjs plays a role - it'll watch node and restart it if it ever stops due to an exception/error etc.

The second type of restart is a machine reboot. This is something that you might want to do if there is a kernel panic etc. AWS will not automatically reboot; it won't do anything that your desktop would do. You're going to have to reboot it (but really - try and debug it before having it serve production traffic again). I've run a fair number of servers and this isn't a common issue. The best way to deal with this is to have redundancy and have other servers step in if one fails in such a stark manner.